# Ошибка {"errors":["can't parse date From"]} wb api

Tags: python, requests, wildberries

Пишу бота для работы с вб, отправляю запрос выдает ошибку:

```json
{"errors":["can't parse date From"]}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема

Код запроса:

```py
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': f'{message.text}'}
request = requests.get("https://statistics-api.wildberries.ru/api/v1/supplier/incomes", headers=header)
print(request.text)
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке `API` ожидает, что вы передадите диапазон интересующих вас дат, начальная дата должна быть в поле `From`. А что, описания `API` нет? Если есть, то в вопросе нужно дать на него ссылку. А если описания нет, то это то ещё удовольствие, гадать, какие параметры нужно передавать.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

Comment: Разобрались - напишите сами ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Забыл передать dateFrom в параметрах запроса

Comment: а как вы формируете dateForm? я отправлю date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00'), но выдает ошибку can't parse date From